# Create a file with the content of a struct and potential substructs recursively

Tags: c, struct

Let us assume that you have a C-struct with potentially sub-structs or array of the latter.

File 1:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t timestamp;
  data_frame frames[2];
} data_set;
```

File 2, somewhere else:

```
typedef struct {
  uint32_t value1;
  uint32_t value2;
  uint16_t status;
} data_frame;
```

The definition of the structs may be in different files all over the source code.

Data of type `data_set` will eventually be sent byte-by-byte through some communication interface. The consumer only gets a blob of bytes and there is **no** information inside the data sent about its nature. However, the consumer should have access to an automatically created file in which the struct data_set and all of its substructs are defined, so that he can decode the received data. The format of this file is currently irrelevant (e.g. a C header file), it should just contain all relevant information.

So I want to automatically and flexibly create such a file based on my large source code.

What would be an efficient way to do this? I thought about using doxygen and its xml output, but it seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Protobuf, ASN.1

Comment: "The definition of the structs may be in different files all over the source code." **This** is a problem. Why? It's like having important laws of the land scattered among many parliament acts and court rulings... no, wait a minute... anyway, you start with designing an interchange format. Once you have it, you describe it with a clean minimal set of header files. Then you use these files in your project *and* give them to your consumers. If you have already done it the wrong way, you should bite the bullet and refactor.